# Wrong syntax highlighting of Python default arguments

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

**Update**: I have filed [a bug with highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2713)

---

`None` should be the same colour in the function signature and function body (since it's the same object being referred to), but instead it's plain in the signature and orange in the body.

[image: Dark mode screenshot] [image: Light mode screenshot]

The code itself:

```py
def my_func(working_list=None):
    if working_list is None:
        working_list = []

    working_list.append("a")
    print(working_list)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366430/4518341)

For comparison, here's what it looks like in [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)), [PythonAnywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PythonAnywhere), and [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit), which are all using different highlighting schemes:

[image: Atom]

[image: PythonAnywhere]

[image: gedit]

Comment: The highlighter recognizes the code as Python. The `None` in the function signature isn't enclosed in a `<span class="hljs-literal">` (which the `None` in the code is), but is part of a straight text node child of the `<span class="hljs-params">` (i.e. the list of parameters). If a string is used in the parameter list, then it's enclosed in a `<span class="hljs-string">`. This looks like a parsing issue, which can/should be [an issue for highlight.js](//github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues). That doesn't mean it's not a problem for SO, just that it will need to be fixed in the library.

Comment: @martijn why did you hammer this question to that one :D

Comment: @Makyen FWIW I've noticed that highlight.js *deliberately* does some really misguided stuff, like attempting to colour entire syntactic structures instead of just tokens.

Comment: @Antti That question explains where to report bugs with highlight.js. So it's not a direct duplicate, but it does answer my question.

Comment: [Maintainer of Highlight.js here]  This is likely a quite simple grammar issue.  If anyone can confirm it's still an issue with the latest Highlight.js please file an issue and we can fix it.